# bitnami django, solution to restarting service?

Tags: django, bitnami

Hey I use installed bitnami django 1.3.0,

but whenever I add changes to urls.py or views.py in my system due to some error. The error won't disappear after refresh.

I have to restart my bitnami Service, "stop" and then "start" it, which is time consuming, I feel like I'm coding C# apps in visual studio.  Sometimes even that doesn't work, I have to sometimes restart my computer and then I suddenly realize "oh wow, the error is solved now!"

Any solution to this? Why does everything require a runserver / restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache for deploy your application in production but use the Django server for development. You will need to configure your application for being served by apache later (modifying the settings.py and the apache configuration file) but during the development you won't need to restart the server for every change.

Comment: and how would I reconfigure bitnami or apache setup to use the "django server for development"? Is there a guide somewhere ?

Comment: You don't need change anything. Just start the django server with `python manage.py runserver` and work on your project. Once your application is ready for production you need to configure apache to serve your application. It will depend of your specific configuration and url mapping. This part more Apache related than django itself. (Don't hesitate to let me know if you find any issue with that, here or directly in bitnami forums)

Answer (score 0):

Everything requires a restart because of the way that the python process operates. It does not reload the file when it's changed (outside of runserver..which is an anomaly, and just there for convenience)

Python execution isn't like PHP execution in that way, and your code isn't dynamically loaded on every page refresh, it's loaded on every server restart.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Isn't that a serious disadvantage for python, then there is no way python can overtake php then until someone solves this. This makes for incredibly slow development and stopping and starting a service takes forever.

Comment: There are loads of tradeoffs that get made when you pick a platform, and when laguages, platforms, and frameworks get designed and developed. You pick the ones that work well for you. This is one of the things that, while slightly annoying coming from a PHP background into Python, turns out to be totally reasonable for me. I do 100% of my development locally with runserver (which DOES refresh) and then you deploy your code out somewhere else, which DOES take a noticeable amount of time. It's not so bad though, because the language and framework are awesome.

Comment: Again I don't understand what do you mean it does refresh locally. My server is local and I have to stop and restart service every time now.